# Set multiple column values from previous row using Postgres SQL

Tags: sql

Assume you have a series of responses from people on what their favorite colors are. This information is stored in a SQL table:

```
| id | favorite_color | friend_recommendation_id |
|----|----------------|--------------------------|
| 1  | green          |                          |
| 2  | blue           |                          |
| 3  | yellow         |                          |
| 4  | green          |                          |
| 5  | yellow         |                          |
| 6  | green          |                          |
```

My goal is to write a Postgres SQL query that would fill the `friend_recommendation` column with the id of the *most recent* person to respond with the same color as the provided individual. This would result in the following table:

```
| id | favorite_color | friend_recommendation_id |
|----|----------------|--------------------------|
| 1  | green          |                          |
| 2  | blue           |                          |
| 3  | yellow         |                          |
| 4  | green          | 1                        |
| 5  | yellow         | 3                        |
| 6  | green          | 4                        |
```

Note that id `6` is filled with `4` and not `1`

I've tried using variables and subselects, but am struggling with how to apply the select for **each** result from the parent query.

Comment: what is your rdbms? Oracle, Postgres?

Comment: Postgres. Updating question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to calculate the field

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0948/1)**

```
SELECT "id", "favorite_color", (SELECT MAX("id")
                                FROM colors c2
                                WHERE c2."favorite_color" = c1."favorite_color"
                                  AND c2."id" < c1."id"
                                ) as friend_recommendation_id 
FROM colors c1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | favorite_color | friend_recommendation_id |
|----|----------------|--------------------------|
|  1 |          green |                   (null) |
|  2 |           blue |                   (null) |
|  3 |         yellow |                   (null) |
|  4 |          green |                        1 |
|  5 |         yellow |                        3 |
|  6 |          green |                        4 |
```

Can also be write like this:

```
SELECT c1."id", c1."favorite_color", MAX(c2."id") as friend_recommendation_id 
FROM colors c1
LEFT JOIN colors c2
       ON c2."favorite_color" = c1."favorite_color"
      AND c2."id" < c1."id"
GROUP BY c1."id", c1."favorite_color"
ORDER BY c1."id";
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE colors target
SET "friend_recomendation_id"  = ( SELECT MAX("id")
                                   FROM colors c2
                                   WHERE c2."favorite_color" = target."favorite_color"
                                     AND c2."id" < target."id")
```

Comment: The output is exactly what I'd expect. If I understand correctly, this is not persisted to the db. What is the syntax to update the table?